# Make transparent the body content but with a div in the content opaque on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working with JQuery and I want to make the body content transparent except for one div on page load, which should be opaque.

I have done this much ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>JQuery Query</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $( "#trans" ).addClass( "getTransparent" );
       $( "#opaq" ).addClass( "getOpaque" );

      });
   </script>
   <style>

   body{

       background-color: #F0FFFF; 
    }
   .myClass{

       height: 100px;
       background-color: #4863A0;

    }
   .getTransparent{

        opacity: 0.3;  

    }
    .getOpaque{

        opacity: 1 !important;

     }
     </style>

 </head>
      <body id="trans">

 <div id="opaq" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 myClass">
 This is supposed to be opaque to every detail...
 </div> 

      </body>
 </html>
```

**The page loads but with not the result I want. The whole page is transparent on load including the div for which I have set the opacity to 1.**
What am I less with or what has to modified to make it work.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s happens because your div lies inside body, so those div get opacity 0.3 as its parent

you should create something like that to reach result

```
<body>
    <div class="transparent"></div>
    <div class="opaque"></div>
</body>
```

and this way you should add position:absolute and z-index property to put opaque div over the transparent

Comment: so is not possible then ? Bootstrap modal though does this kind of stuff.

Comment: Okay let me have a try at things you have suggested. thankyou.

Comment: not the same, see my edit, its should be another div over the main content, and in this case thay add a new layer with 100% height and width, that lies over the other page content, go through this example http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/

Comment: Opacity has not been discussed in the article. They have played with the background color which is not my requirement.

Comment: there is no such difference in this case, you may add black color to div tag and then add opacity or get the same result using rgba color scheme, I show this article to show you main principlec of how it should be solved

Comment: here is a some sketche for you, hope it would help
http://codepen.io/luninroman/pen/pyeeqG

Comment: I am late to accept your answer as the accepted solution. It actually has worked. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hack in css :

```
   background-color: rgba(72,99,160,0.3);//#4863A0;
```

see here https://jsfiddle.net/bw08dv7g/

Comment: I have to do something with opacity. This would just change the background color.